RNScreens Failed to initialise dummy layout in onHostResume
react-native latest version give the issue
[RNScreens] Failed to initialise dummy layout in onHostResume
package.json
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^8.0.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.34.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  }



I found the same issue on RN 0.75 Disabling bridgless mode works fine for me as mentioned on
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/2324#issuecomment-2334659956
